# How to change a size of a window without using "resize"

Tags: python, image-processing, image-resizing

Does anyone know how to change a size of a window without changing its quality? (Or stretch an image without using resizing)

I have a (320, 240) image, and I want to display them (albeit at a lower quality) in a (640, 480) size window without resorting to resizing functions?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is confusing: "...how to change a window without changing its quality.... I want to display them (albeit at a lower quality)..." When you say not using resizing functions, what functions are you referring to?

Comment: I believe the question refers to scaling an image with nearest neighbor interpolation to avoid blurring.